# Smooth manifolds and cartesian products

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

So assume you have two smooth maps $f:M\rightarrow N$ and $g:P\rightarrow Q$. If we define the map $f\times g:M\times P\rightarrow N\times Q$ to be such that $(f\times g)(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$. Does it follow that such a map is smooth?

Comment: Yes, of course. Everything reduces to charts, where it is just locally the map $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x), g(y))$ composed of smooth functions.

Comment: Recall that the charts on a product are the product of charts.  Therefore, locally, you have a chart where $f$ is smooth and a chart where $g$ is smooth.